# generic hash map

Tags: generics, java-hashmap

Делаю класс кэша для того что бы в него можно было кешировать любые объекты. Но компилятор просит создать отдельный метод для каждого класса

```
 /*
 * jsock framework https://github.com/nnpa/jsock open source
 * Each line should be prefixed with  * 
 */
package jsock.core;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * public static class GenericCache<K, V>
 * @author nn
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class JCache<K, V> {

    public static JCache instance;

    public  Map<K, V> cache = new HashMap<K, V>();  

    public static HashMap<String,Integer> expiries = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public static int checkTime = 30000;

    public static java.util.Timer timer;

    public JCache(){

    }

    public  void set(K key, V value,int time){  
        instance.remove( key);

        instance.cache.put(key, value);  

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int lifeTime     =   (int) (currentTime + time);

        instance.expiries.put((String) key, lifeTime);

    }  

     //Generic method  
     public  V get(K key){  
         return cache.get(key);  
     }

     /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    public static synchronized JCache getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new JCache();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void runTimer(){

        timer   =   new java.util.Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (String key : expiries.keySet()) {
                    int time         = expiries.get(key);
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if(time < currentTime){
                        instance.expiries.remove(key);
                        instance.remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        },checkTime);
    }

    /**
     * remove cache
     * @param key 
     */
    public void remove(K key){
        instance.remove(key);
        instance.expiries.remove(key);
    }

}
```

Пример использования:

```
Users user = new Users();
user.byId(session.user_id);

webUser = user;

JCache.set(token,user);
```

Ошибка компиляции:

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: jsock.core.JCache.set at
jsock.task.JClientTask.loadUser(JClientTask.java:109) at
jsock.task.JClientTask.beforeAction(JClientTask.java:85) at
jsock.task.JTask.run(JTask.java:26) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPool‌​Executor.java:1142) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoo‌​lExecutor.java:617)
```

Comment: c Object тоже не получается

Comment: Было бы очень здорово увидеть полный текст ошибки компиляции. Также небольшое замечание: метод `set` принимает три параметра (`key`, `value`, `time`), передаётся же только два параметра (`token`, `user`).

Comment: Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: jsock.core.JCache.set
 at jsock.task.JClientTask.loadUser(JClientTask.java:109)
 at jsock.task.JClientTask.beforeAction(JClientTask.java:85)
 at jsock.task.JTask.run(JTask.java:26)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: `JCache` - это переменная? если да, то покажите как она описана. если нет, то `set` - это метод объекта и его модно вызывать только у объекта.

Comment: Добавил ответ ниже. Сейчас еще раз попробую

Answer (score 0):

Работает такой вариант

```
/*
 * jsock framework https://github.com/nnpa/jsock open source
 * Each line should be prefixed with  * 
 */
package jsock.core;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * public static class GenericCache<K, V>
 * @author nn
 * @param <K>
 * @param <V>
 */
public class JCache<K, V> {

    public static JCache instance;

    public  Map<K, V> cache = new HashMap<K, V>();  

    public static HashMap<String,Integer> expiries = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    public static int checkTime = 30000;

    public static java.util.Timer timer;

    public JCache(){

    }

    public  void set(K key, V value,int time){  

        instance.cache.put(key, value);  

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int lifeTime     =   (int) (currentTime + time);

        instance.expiries.put((String) key, lifeTime);

    }  

     //Generic method  
     public  V get(K key){  
         return cache.get(key);  
     }

     /**
     * 
     * @return 
     */
    public static synchronized JCache getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new JCache();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void runTimer(){

        instance.timer   =   new java.util.Timer();

        instance.timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (String key : instance.expiries.keySet()) {
                    int time         = instance.expiries.get(key);
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if(time < currentTime){
                        instance.expiries.remove(key);
                        instance.remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        },instance.checkTime);
    }

    /**
     * remove cache
     * @param key 
     */
    public  void remove(K key){
        instance.remove(key);
        instance.expiries.remove(key);
    }

}
```

Использование

```
String token    = message.json.get("auth_token").toString();

JCache cache = JCache.getInstance();
Users obj = (Users) cache.get(token);


if (obj == null) {

    Session session = new Session();
    session.findByToken(token);

    Users user = new Users();
    user.byId(session.user_id);

    webUser = user;

    int time = 120000;

    cache.set(token,user,time);

} else {
     webUser = (Users) cache.get(token);
}
```

Comment: это не является ответом. у вас код в вопросе с ошибкой.

Comment: Ну так я отлаживаю, сейчас доотлаживаю и выложу что получилось

Comment: почитайте [ask]